# Configure PartitionKey using Semantic Logging Windows Azure

Tags: logging, azure

I am trying to configure Semantinc Logging out of the process to write to Azure.

I finally managed to write events into a Table storage. My problem is how do I define PartitionKey.

I just inserted a couple of tests and the PartitionKeys are:

```
2520107100599999999
2520107103599999999
```

I would like to have the partitions defined by me (for instance, partition by day).

How do I do that?

This is my actual configuration

```
<windowsAzureTableSink name="Windows Azure Storage" instanceName="xxxxxxx" connectionString="xxxxxxx">
    <sources>
        <eventSource name="myCompany" level="Error"/>
    </sources>
</windowsAzureTableSink>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for having customized PartitionKey?

Comment: I like to have daily partitions

Comment: @guarav query performance over non-partition and rowkey columns is poor, you need to force searchable information into those two columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer to your question but I'm guessing that you would want to specify partition by day because you would want to query this data on a date basis. Assuming this is correct, you can still achieve this with the current partitioning scheme. Essentially the PartitionKey you see represents date/time value. This is how it is derived:

```
DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks
```

The PartitionKey value has minute level granularity. So if you apply the logic above, `2520107100599999999` essentially translates to `2014-02-05T08:59:00Z`.

Again, I may be wrong in my assumption and if that's the case, please let me know and I'll delete the answer. Thought I would post it as it is not really obvious that a date/time value can be derived from PartitionKey value.

Comment: Any idea how to change the partition definition?

Comment: I don't think so unless you go and change it in the library's source code.

Comment: This is where in the source code you will make the change: http://slab.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#source/Src/SemanticLogging.WindowsAzure/Sinks/DateTimeExtensions.cs.